# On creating VCard not getting contact image and notes in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cncontactstore

Fetching contact list using CNContactStore and converting complete contact list to VCard, all are coming fine except i am not getting contact image and notes.

```
   NSMutableArray *contactsArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
   CNContactStore *store = [[CNContactStore alloc] init];
   [store requestAccessForEntityType:CNEntityTypeContacts completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    if (!granted) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        });
        return;
    }
    NSMutableArray *contacts = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSError *fetchError;

    CNContactFetchRequest *request = [[CNContactFetchRequest alloc] initWithKeysToFetch:@[[CNContactVCardSerialization descriptorForRequiredKeys], [CNContactFormatter descriptorForRequiredKeysForStyle:CNContactFormatterStyleFullName]]];

    BOOL success = [store enumerateContactsWithFetchRequest:request error:&fetchError usingBlock:^(CNContact *contact, BOOL *stop) {
        [contacts addObject:contact];
    }];
    if (!success) {
        NSLog(@"error = %@", fetchError);
    }

    for (CNContact *contact in contacts) {
        CNContact *contact1 = contact.mutableCopy;
        [contactsArray addObject:contact1];
    }

    NSData *vcardString =[CNContactVCardSerialization dataWithContacts:contactsArray error:&error];

    vcardStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:vcardString encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"vcardStr = %@",vcardStr);
  }];
```

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: No i didn't get anwer

Comment: you can create PHOTO & NOTE field inside of VCard. CNContactVCardSerialization does not use any photo of contact.

Comment: I have been trying to do something similar.  Did you figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

Contact Profile images from CNContact

```
 if (granted == YES) {
 NSArray *keys = @[CNContactFamilyNameKey, CNContactGivenNameKey, CNContactPhoneNumbersKey, CNContactImageDataKey];
 NSString *containerId = store.defaultContainerIdentifier;
 NSPredicate *predicate = [CNContact predicateForContactsInContainerWithIdentifier:containerId];
 NSError *error;
 NSArray *Contacts = [store unifiedContactsMatchingPredicate:predicate keysToFetch:keys error:&error];
 if (error)
 {
    //error
 } 
else 
{    
for (CNContact *contact in Contacts)
{
UIImage *contactProfileImage;
if (contact.imageDataAvailable) 
{
  UIImage * image = [UIImage imageWithData:contact.imageData];
  contactProfileImage = image; 
}
else
{
  contactProfileImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon.png"];
}
}
```

Comment: In contact i am not getting key for image. so this method can't be use.

Comment: If i use predicate key then CNContactVCardSerialization is not working hence it will return nil.